# My in-game meshes are inverted in unity after importing from 3ds MAX with skin

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

My in-game meshes are inverted in unity after importing from 3ds MAX with skin,

both the mesh and the normals look "upside down", like if i was looking at some kind of ghost.

if i uncheck skin, it works correctly.

Comment: Quite. While you're at it, remember (a) models in the 3D industry **MUST BE** in z-forward; (b) it's essential to use actual meters as your units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1 : setup the model and export as FBX.

step 2 : import in unity. the vertex and the normals will be flipped.

step 3 : attach this c# script, and run ONLY ONCE.

```
public class meshInverter : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().sharedMesh;
        mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

step 4: remove last script, attach this JS script, and run ONLY ONCE:

```
#pragma strict
import System.Linq;
function Start () {
    var mesh = (transform.GetComponent("SkinnedMeshRenderer") as SkinnedMeshRenderer).sharedMesh;
    var normals : Vector3[] = mesh.normals;
    for (var i=0;i<normals.Length;i++){
        normals[i] = -normals[i];
    }
    mesh.normals = normals;
}

function Update () {

}
```

step 5: remove last script, and now that the model is fixed.

**Edit**

Make sure too that your bones o mesh doesn't have any negative scale, that could fuck it up too and would not be a .fbx export failure.

Comment: although this is admirable, I definitely would not do this.  FIX THE MODEL in Max.

Comment: until i find the hell's going on when exporting this concrete skinned and perfectly fine model, this'll be okay.

Comment: damn o_o how the hell did a negative scale got in there? i've never ever scaled anything :/

Comment: Negative scale gets applied for example when you use the mirror tool.